# Parse OrderId into Fooman PDF template file

Tags: pdf

I'm stuck trying to parse an OrderId into a PDF template in order to get QTY of Items in the Order but it won't load the ID variable.

I can add the ID as a static value but when I use my variable I get nothing,

Here's my code:

```
<?php

        $orderId = '{{var order.increment_id}}';
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
//      print_r($orderId);
    if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
        $invIncrementIDs = array();
        $invItems = array();
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
            $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
            foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $invItems[] = $item->getQty();
                $total = $total + ($item->getQty());
            }
        }
    }
?>
<h3>
    <strong><?php echo $this->__("Number of items:") ?><?php echo $total; ?></strong>
</h3>
```

The above doesn't work but parsing in the static value does:

```
<?php

        $orderId = '{{var order.increment_id}}';
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('1000003');
//      print_r($orderId);
    if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
        $invIncrementIDs = array();
        $invItems = array();
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
            $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
            foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $invItems[] = $item->getQty();
                $total = $total + ($item->getQty());
            }
        }
    }
?>
<h3>
    <strong><?php echo $this->__("Number of items:") ?><?php echo $total; ?></strong>
</h3>
```

I'm absolutely baffled!

Comment: Have you tried using Fooman's PDF Helper to get the order that way?  `$orderId = Mage::helper('fooman/pdf')->getOrder()->getIncrementId()`  Not entirely sure this'll work, but it's a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing of the phtml template happens after the php is evaluated. So when your loadByIncrementId is getting executed it will look for `'{{var order.increment_id}}'` Also the `{{ }}` needs to be in the output to be replaced, in other words it can't be in php and needs to be in the html part of the template.

Don is very close

```
$orderId = $this->getPdfHelper()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

But you can save yourself the loading part and just do

```
$order = $this->getPdfHelper()->getOrder();
```

Comment: Thankyou for the tip, it has saved me hours of baffledness, Out of curiousity would I be able to load the Shipping method that was chosen using the same `getPdfHelper()` method? I need to do an IF statement in order to `hide/show` the shipping method logo...

Comment: Once you have the order this is all possible. So just $order->getShippingMethod()